# Is there a way to display current weather on lollipop lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop

It seems lock screen widgets have been removed in lollipop. Google now has a weather notification but it does not show up on the lock screen. Is there a way to get this or any other weather information on to the lock screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a decent number of 3rd party weather apps that have an option to add the current weather conditions to your notification bar. Consequently, enabling one of these persistent weather notifications will add the entry to your lock screen as well.

I personally use [1Weather](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.expressweather), which looks like this:

[image]

This is (in my experience) a pretty common feature for weather apps, so you could "shop around" a bit for one that you like.

Answer (score -1):

Dashclock also lets you put various info on the lockscreen - temperature, battery charge, number of new emails, etc.

Comment: Dashclock doesn't work on Lollipop, as far as I'm aware.